# Look up tables for 8 digit display

Tags: microcontroller, led, digital-logic, communication, stm32f4

My project on STM32f407-Discovery. I will send a message on terminal to my board and I use this message for showing an 8-digit display. I am trying to build a look up table for the 8 digit Display. I will use it for counter but I don't know where am I starting. Can I use a switch case build for it? Please, help.

Comment: The whole point of a LUT is to avoid using a switch structure.

Comment: a look up table is ideally a single read with some ideally simple math (a shift and an add hopefully).  where a switch statement sometimes may optimize into that, worst case is a very long very slow if-then-else tree.

Comment: I assume you know how to control each segment separately?  and then blink two segments one at a time back and forth and so on to give the illusion of them all being on?  as you figure that out you can/will determine which pins control which segment.  then you simply lay out a table as answered below.  and feed that into your code that is blinking segments at some rate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use *switch* or lookup. I'm not familiar with the device but this pseudo-code may give you some clues.

```
// +--a--+
// f     b
// +--g--+ 
// e     c
// +--d--+

switch (char){
  //                 abcdefg segments
  case "A": segs = 0b1110111;
  case "B": segs = 0b0011111;
  case "C": etc.
}
```

Alternatively define all the patterns in a lookup table.

```
int segs[65] = 0b1110111;    // A
int segs[66] = 0b0011111;    // B
int segs[67] = etc.

port0 = segs[char];
```

Comment: The compiler may not like "int segs[65] = 0b1110111;" You may have more luck with "char upper[26]; upper[0] = 0x77;..." to create the lookup table and then "if ((input<='A') && (input >='Z'))  segs = upper[input-'A'];" to read the value.